# Minecraft convert block to entity form

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I play minecraft with [Industrial Craft^2](http://forum.industrial-craft.net/index.php?page=Thread&threadID=767), [Buildcraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/286417-181-buildcraft-1811-211-pipes-quarry-auto-crafting-building-engines/)(with [Extra Buildcraft Pipes](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/474348-173-2012-extrabuildcraftpipes/)), [RedPower](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/365357-181-173-eloraams-mods-rp2pr1-redpower-v171-integrated-redstone-now-redpower-logic-redstone-pipe/) and [Equivalent Exchange](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/364525-181-equivalent-exchange-v416/). I want to build a automatic cobblestone factory that could fill a chest with cobblestone and send the overflow to my Mass Fabricator.

My question is how to convert a block to its entity form so I can send it through my pipe system.

Comment: blow it up​​​​?

Comment: Seems kind wasteful, about 70% of block are destoryed(minecraft wiki).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, if you are using build craft, don't bother with a cobblestone factory, just work toward a building a quarry and you will have all the cobblestone you could ever want.

When I make my quarries, I usually filter out the cobblestone and feed it in to a chain of 6 double chests and then feed the overflow in to IC's recyclers.

Comment: I ended up building a few quarrys and setting them to super huge sizes, i'll let them run overnight and see what I get.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [automated miner.](http://minecraftbuildcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Miners)

You make a cobblestone generator that using pistons to push the cobblestone into the area that the autominer mines.

Comment: Cool, there kinda expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the mods you're using, but the piston mod that was popular before official pistons had the property that two pistons pushing a block at the same time would convert it to a resource entity; there are YouTube videos of cobblestone generators using this feature.